# Is there a way to run google docs script under the script owner's authorization?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet that is a master database of orders entered by a number of dealers. Therefore, this master sheet must have limited edit access.  I want created a number of other sheets (one for each dealer) through which they can enter orders and added to my master sheet via a script running in those sheets. Is this possible?  When I tried this, it denied them access to the master sheet.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

One work around that I've used for this problem is to set an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run on a regular time interval.

Installable triggers run on the owner of the trigger's authority, so it will be able to access both the main spreadsheet as well as each dealer's. The trick is to assign a timed trigger to a function that checks each dealer's sheet for updates and then makes the appropraite change to the main spreadsheet. You'll want to be sure that the trigger doesn't take too long to run or run too frequently since you have a [limited amount of script run time each day](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Something like the following:

```
function myTrigger() {
  var time = new Date();
  // maybe check to see if it's night or other times that dealers won't update
  // that way you can return early and don't waste quota hours

  var dealerSpreadsheetIds = ["id1", "id2", ...];
  var dealerSheetName = "Deals";

  for (var i = 0; i < dealerSpreadsheetIds.length; i++) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dealerSpreadsheetIds[i]).getSheetByName(dealerSheetName);
    // check Deals sheet ranges for updates
    // if there is an update, update the main spreadsheet
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to do the reverse, meaning have the dealer sheets run the trigger and update the main sheet.    Still, I'll try your suggestion.  How do you set the time when the trigger will run?  Sorry if I am asking a very basic question - I have never used installable triggers before.

Comment: No worries. Inside the script file, click Resources > Current project's triggers. A dialog will open up on which you can click "Add a new trigger". A row should be added to the trigger table where you can select the script to "Run" and the "Event" to trigger the script. Select "Time-driven" in the "Event" column. Then select the timer schedule and how often to execute the script.

Comment: If you want, you can give the dealers the appearance of updating the main database by having them run a script that stores their updates into a hidden sheet that they have edit access to. That sheet can act like an outbox in an office, where the secretary (your timed script) has access to all the areas the forms need to be moved but the employee doesn't necessarily need to have access.

Comment: I came up with the same concept of the hidden sheet to act as an outbox.  So when the dealers submit an order, it just sits in this hidden sheet until the script in the master sheet goes and "gets" this order.  It works great.  Once I set up the timed trigger in the master sheet to go "get" everything from the "outbox", the function will be complete.  Only potential problem is that dealers can unhide this outbox sheet and manipulate the data prior to the master sheet getting it.  I can't think of a work around for that, can you?  Thanks for all your help, by the way.